# Access Union same table won't update

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table with 2 pk companyid and articlecode then 
price1,price2,price3,price4
like this

articles table:

```
companyid | articlecode | price1 | price2 | price3 | price4
1  | 10001 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
2  | 10001 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
...
```

then i want to have:

```
companyid articlecode PriceName Price
1 | 10001 | Price1 | 1
1 | 10001 | Price2 | 2
1 | 10001 | Price3 | 3
1 | 10001 | Price4 | 4
```

I have this union:

```
SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode,"Price 1", Articles.price1
FROM Articles 
Where
Articles.articlecode = '10001' And Articles.companyid = '1'
Union
SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode, "Price 2", Articles.price2
FROM Articles 
Where
Articles.articlecode = '10001' And Articles.companyid = '1'
Union
SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode, "Price 3", Articles.price3
FROM Articles 
Where
Articles.articlecode = '10001' And Articles.companyid = '1'
Union
SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode, "Price 4", Articles.price4
FROM Articles 
Where
Articles.articlecode = '10001' And Articles.companyid = '1'
```

I want to update the prices in access but won't let me, any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is important that your columns of the UNION subqueries have the same name (for example `price` instead of `price1`, `price2`, ..).

To obtain the table you want (and filter it) you can use:

```
SELECT companyid, articlecode, PriceName, Price
FROM (
    SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode,"Price 1" as PriceName, Articles.price1 as Price
    FROM Articles 
    UNION
    SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode,"Price 2" as PriceName, Articles.price2 as Price
    FROM Articles 
    UNION
    SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode,"Price 3" as PriceName, Articles.price3 as Price
    FROM Articles 
    UNION
    SELECT Articles.companyid, Articles.articlecode,"Price 4" as PriceName, Articles.price4 as Price
    FROM Articles 
) t
WHERE articlecode='10001' AND companyid='1';
```

To do an update you have to use the original table:

```
UPDATE Articles SET price1=1.2, price2=2.2 WHERE articlecode='10001' AND companyid='1';
```

**Edit:** Although you can edit data in some queries, [you cannot edit data in all query](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Edit-data-in-a-query-6ca3edfc-6d66-4d90-8219-c2b258d5bed7#bmcannot):

> You can never edit the data in a query when:
>
> - The query is a crosstab query.
> - The query is a SQL-specific query.
> - The field you are trying to edit is a calculated field. In this case, you may be able to edit the other fields.
> - The query is based on three or more tables and there is a many-to-one-to-many relationship.  NOTE   Although you cannot edit the
>     query datasheet in this case, you can edit the data in a form when the
>     RecordsetType property of the form is set to Dynaset (Inconsistent
>     Updates).
> - The query contains a GROUP BY clause.

In this case we are using a SQL specific query.

**Edit 2:** To edit your data anyway there are some workarounds:

- Use the `UPDATE` query indicated above.
- Use the original table `Article` which contains all data anyway.
- Use VBA, as mentioned in: [How do I make an editable UNION query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261959/how-do-i-make-an-editable-union-query).

Comment: so there isn't a way that i can't do this?

Comment: You can write the data to a temporary table, edit this, and read back the data to the original fields. Or better: Update your table schema to respect normalization.